# ROS HYDRO roslaunch was not found

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had installed the ros hydro for use in a JACO, but when i try to use roslaunch, says roslaunch was not found. I search in the directory /opt/ros/hydro/share   and there isn't the folder roslaunch

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187677/ros-hydro-roslaunch-was-not-found/) by [Priscila Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/19770/priscila-martins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sterlingm](https://answers.ros.org/users/2199/sterlingm/) on 2014-07-24**:
Check in /opt/ros/hydro/bin for a roslaunch executable. Also, have you sourced the setup file for Hydro - "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the folder `/opt/ros/hydro/share` does not exists you haven't installed the Debian package `ros-hydro-roslaunch`.
Try installing it with `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-roslaunch`.

How did you install ROS Hydro in the first place? It seems like you didn't follow the tutorials. May be you want to do that to make sure to have all base ROS packages and not lacking other packages too.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Priscila Martins](https://answers.ros.org/users/19770/priscila-martins/) on 2014-07-24**:
Thank you so much. It's works.